# OneToMany relationsip of entity in persistence context is not updated

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

There is 3 entities in MxN relationship, B being association entity. We create them in single TX, persist all of them, and fetch entity with OneToMany association. This association is not initialized after fetch.

Source: https://github.com/alfonz19/springboot222demo/commits/what

```
    @Transactional
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
//      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            UUID aId = UUID.randomUUID();
            AEntity aEntity = aRepository.save(new AEntity().setId(aId));
            UUID bId = UUID.randomUUID();
            CEntity cEntity = cRepository.save(new CEntity().setId(bId));
            em.flush();

            bRepository.save(new BEntity().setAEntity(aEntity).setCEntity(cEntity));
//      }

        em.flush();
//      em.clear();

        Iterable<CEntity> centities = cRepository.findAll();
        List<BEntity> bEntities =
                iterableToStream(centities).flatMap(e -> e.getBEntities().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Assert.assertThat(centities, Matchers.iterableWithSize(1));
        Assert.assertThat(bRepository.findAll(), Matchers.iterableWithSize(1));
        Assert.assertThat(bEntities.size(), CoreMatchers.is(1));
...
}
```

Ok, I understand, that when creating `BEntity` I do not update `AEntity` and `CEntity` leaving them corrupted. Calling `cRepository.findAll()` then does call select on db to get all Cs (even without any evict/flush/clear) but leaves @OneToMany uninitialized. I don't get it. I would understand, if there woulndn't be no call to db at all, but if I fetch Cs anyway to refresh it, why not refresh also the association table. Why's that?

<s>Even more suprisingly `aRepository.save(new AEntity().setId(aId))` when doing em.merge (entity has assigned id) the hibernate does load whole MxN structure using 2 left outer joins, even if @OneToMany is lazy. Why's that??</s> EDIT: ok, that's not surprising at all, that's implication of cascade merge. Compeletely ok.

<s>I'm little bit surprised by this behavior, as there are select issued where they shouldn't be (IIUC), and there aren't ones, where they easily could be.</s>

And to keep the best to the end. With small change: uncommenting for loop and clear, I'm getting full nondeterministic behavior.

source: https://github.com/alfonz19/springboot222demo/tree/nondeterministic

Tests will either work, or produces exception like:

- array out of bounds
- collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance:
- java.lang.NullPointerException

but if I put breakpoint on `bEntities` variable declaration, `cEntities` are always correctly created and test then pass. I have no idea what can cause this.

Answer (score 0):

I have answer to non-deterministic behavior problem bonus-question.

One more randomly generated exceptions to the list is `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Found shared references to a collection` and all this behavior just disappers with removal of `flatMap`. Ie replace:

```
List<BEntity> bEntities =
                StreamSupport.stream(centities.spliterator(), true).flatMap(e -> e.getBEntities().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with

```
List<BEntity> bEntities = new LinkedList<>();
        centities.forEach(e->bEntities.addAll(e.getBEntities()));
```

and test in (not anymore) "nondeterministic" branch will pass 100%. Not sure why, however it seems, that stream-api is not that safe with hibernate-managed collections.